Container Pre-Stop when utilizing Chiseled Container
I am currently running a full featured Ubuntu container within my Kubernetes cluster.  However I would like to migrate everything to a chiseled container.  It has been common to utilize a script within the container lifecycle to pause and handle the SIGTERM command to execute a number of items. This is ranging from a simple sleep for a specified amount of time, to complex executions ensuring all active transactions are complete, or inflight data is properly committed.
Without a shell within the container, is there an approach others have found to accomplish similar items with the chiseled Ubuntu?

What is the version of type of Ubuntu you are running?
